# Entering visual mode is selecting whole lines unexpectedly

Tags: visual-mode, visual-block

I'm editing a small bash script:

```
d=$1
  year=$(date -d"$d" +%Y)
  month=$(date -d "$d" +%m)
  day=$(date -d "$d" +%d)
  hive -f /home/gavin_cameron/hive_queries/dc_player_daily_snapshot.hive -d jobYear="$year" -d jobMonth="$month" -d jobDay="$day" > logs/debug_$d.log 2>&1
```

I'd like to delete the 2 spaces for each line for year, month, day and hive.

When I place my cursor underneath the `d` in `d=$1` and then press <kbd>v</kbd> and then press <kbd>right</kbd> once to cover the white space on the first line and then <kbd>down</kbd> to highlight all the white spaces, the entire lines are highlighted whereas I was expecting just the white space to be highlighted.

Why is that and how can I delete the indentation using visual mode plus delete in a oner rather than line by line deletion?

Comment: Close. Missed by a _Ctrl_. You're looking for Visual _Block_ mode which is entered via `Ctrl+V`. This will confine the selection to a rectangle which you expand/contract with the directional keys. Press `d` when selection is what you want.

Comment: @BLayer You should add this as an answer! (don't use comments for answers...)

Comment: @filbranden I'm aware....but this has to be a duplicate, it's about rudimentary functionality. I'm not able to look right this sec, tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use visual block mode via Ctrl-V, I would suggest a re-indenting tool (since that’s your goal).

Meet `=`. It’s an operator. It takes motions and text objects. And it indents things.

I would do `=ip` from anywhere in your block of code.